# PayPal Button - Custom URL Parameter

Tags: paypal

I would like to setup a simple PayPal button on my website, however I need to send and receive a few custom parameters.

I have generated some basic button code:
(eg https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=MXR9J7XQ4SW3N)

I need to pass and receive back 2 parameters:
- Customer_ID
- Product_ID

Usually I would do something like this:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=MXR9J7XQ4SW3N&***Customer_ID=1&Product_ID=1***

But I would I receive those parameters back after the payment is complete?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using variables that PayPal would recognize the ones you're trying to add will be ignored and dropped by PayPal - same with if you're using hosted buttons (you can't modify the variables and values for a hosted button through HTML or just appending them to a URL).

You can use `custom` and `item_number` to pass your "customer_id" and "product_id" values to PayPal. You'll get them back through PDT and IPN as well.